# How to initialize C++ reference with different constructors based on condition?

Tags: c++, reference

The reference variable `foo` below is initialized with either an instance of `Foo` or its derived class `Bar` based on `condition`. Strangely enough, based on the output of the `say()` method, `foo` seems to be an instance of `Foo` rather than an instance of `Bar` — why?

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual void say() const {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    virtual void say() const {
        std::cout << "Bar\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr bool condition = false;
    const Foo& foo = condition ? Foo() : Bar();
    foo.say();   // outputs "Foo” ???                                                                                                  
    return 0;
}
```

If I annotate each constructor I can see that the `Bar` constructor is getting invoked when evaluating the ternary expression. If I annotate each destructor I see that `Bar` destructor is invoked *before* `foo` is initialized — this tells me that a temporary `Bar` object is created by the ternary operator, but is destroyed before initialization — why?

Compiled with (Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2))

```
clang++ -Wall -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with

```
const Foo& foo = condition ? Foo() : Bar();
```

is that both parts need to return the same type.  Since `Foo()` and `Bar()` aren't the same type, the compiler tries to convert them.  The only valid conversion it can do is to slice `Bar()` into its `Foo` part.  This means no matter what you get, you'll be binding a reference to a `Foo` and the `Bar` part disappears.

To fix this you'll need to use pointers like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Foo {
public:
    virtual ~Foo() = default;  // don't forget to add this when using polymorphism
    virtual void say() const {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
};

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    virtual void say() const {
        std::cout << "Bar\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr bool condition = false;
    auto foo = condition ? std::make_unique<Foo>() : std::make_unique<Bar>();
    foo->say();   // outputs "Bar" now                                                                                                  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Bonus: using unique ptrs saves me from having to explicitly delete as well.

Comment: @wcochran Yeah, not having to write `new` and `delete` is really nice.